# Python - Creating two models with 1-1 relationship in a same model.py file (hierarchy problem) in Django

Tags: python, django, model

Hey I'm facing this problem when I want to create 1:1 relationship
IDK if I'm missing something here or what am I doing wrong

here in one app.model.py I'm trying to create 2 models like below :

```
class Manager(models.Model):
    user_id  = models.ForeignKey('BeautySalon.Salon',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)  #FK
    businessL_id = models.BooleanField(default = False, blank = False)
    salon_id = models.ForeignKey(Salon,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING) #FK

class Salon(models.Model): 
    # name, manager_id--Manager, city_id--City, address, tell, description, starting hour , closing hour, PTG, rank--Rank
   
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=200)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(Manager,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)  # FK
    city =  models.ForeignKey(City,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)  #FK
    address = models.TextField(null = False, max_length = 1000)
    tell = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    description = models.TextField(null= False, max_length = 1000)
    strHour = models.TimeField()
    clsHour = models.TimeField()
    PTG = models.BooleanField(default = False, blank = False)
    rank = models.ForeignKey(Rank,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)  #FK
```

but when I try to make migrations I get this error
`Field defines a relation with model 'Salon', which is either not installed, or is abstract.`

In C++ I would face the same problem but we could call the name at the top to let it know, IDK how to do it in python
I've tried this :
`class Salon (models.Model): pass`
at the top of models.py file, but it didn't work .

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gues the problem is that you're referencing the `Salon` model before it's defined.

Try move `Salon` class before `Manager` class in your code, or just wright it as a string in `models.ForeignKey`

```
class Manager(models.Model):
    ...
    salon_id = models.ForeignKey('Salon', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    ...


class Salon(models.Model)
    ...
    manager = models.ForeignKey('Manager', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    ...
```

Comment: yeah Ik that's the problem, but because in salon I also have ForeignKey to Manager table I get the same error

Comment: Try using string in `models.ForeignKey` as shown in answer

Comment: It worked thanks for your help :)
and do you know what happens in core that I get this error 
what's the difference between using 'Salon' in strings or Salon

Comment: Glad to help :) Using `'Salon'` instead of `Salon`, you're telling Django to use a string reference to the `Salon` model, rather than a direct reference. So, Django can load the `Manager` model without needing to know about the `Salon` model, since it's just a string reference that will be resolved later. Consider accepting the answer, if it was usefull :)